# ¿Por qué el primer parámetro varía?

Tags: javascript

Esta función suma todos los números, pero no entiendo bien cómo funciona en algunos lugares:

***Comenté en el código por qué me parece confuso y en el lugar del código***

```js
function sum(nums) { // RECIBE EL ARRAY
    if (nums.length === 0) { 
       return 0;
    } else {
       const [first, ...rest] = nums;
       /* CREA UNA CONSTANTE QUE RELLAN CON EL ARRAY Y UN PARÁMETRO REST
       */
       return first + sum(rest);
       /*
       EN EL RETURN REALIZA LA SUMA DE FIRST + FIRST + FIRST, PERO FIRST DEBERÍA SER SIEMPRE 4, YA QUE ES EL PRIMER NÚMERO DEL ARRAY, ENTONCES PORQUE NO ES ASI? PORQUE EL VALOR DE FIRST VA CAMBIANDO? 
      */
    }
 }
 var b = [4,3,29,2],
     c = sum(b);
 console.log(c);
```

Comment: la línea de return regresa la suma de `first + elem2 + elem3 + ... +  elemn`. `...rest` toma el resto de los argumentos del parámetro que se le manda a la función a partir de cierto índice, en este caso a partir del índice 1, ya que 0 está asignado para first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo, lo que tienes que saber es que `sum(nums)` es una función recursiva.

La recursividad es una función que se llama a sí misma dentro de la misma función.  [Aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_recursivo) te dejo un poco de lectura.

Ahora bien, llendo al punto creo que a lo que entiendo esta es tu pregunta:

> EN EL RETURN REALIZA LA SUMA DE FIRST + FIRST + FIRST, PERO FIRST
>   DEBERÍA SER SIEMPRE 4, YA QUE ES EL PRIMER NÚMERO DEL ARRAY, ENTONCES
>   PORQUE NO ES ASI? PORQUE EL VALOR DE FIRST VA CAMBIANDO?

**Respuesta:**

La función en el return devuelve siempre la suma de `first`, pero no siempre debería ser cuatro, ya que en la llamada devuelves el resto del arreglo, convirtiendo en el primer elemento, al que estaba como cabezera del resto del arreglo.

Ahora, para que lo veas más gráfico, mira como se ejecutaría:

```
*El recorrido no es en JS, es meramente gráfico*

arr= [4,3,29,2]
sum(arr)


4 + sum([3,29,2])
4 + 3 + sum([29,2])
4 + 3 + 29 + sum([2])
4 + 3 + 29 + 2 + sum([])
4 + 3 + 29 + 2 + 0
```

Sí lo ves, el segundo elemento en la ejecución n, se convierte en el primer elemento en la ejecución n+1, hasta que llegas a la condición final, que es cuando la lista está vacía, devuelves un 0 a la suma de los elementos de la lista

**Entonces:**

con la línea `const [first, ...rest] = nums;`, lo que haces es dividir en dos el arreglo que te entra, el primer elemento será el primer elemento, y el segundo será un arreglo con el resto de la lista. y como ves, cuando llamas a la línea `return first + sum(rest);`, realizas la suma de el primer elemento y lo que te devuelva la función `sum` con el resto de la lista, menos el primer elemento

Comment: Entonces por qué rest cambia? , first siempre será 4, y rest siempre sera desde el 4 en adelante, no debería recorrer el array para sumarlo ? no entiendo realmente , si pudiera ser más detallado por favor, gracias Randall

Comment: Cambia, porque cada vez que se ejecuta el método es con una nueva lista, y cada lista tiene un nuevo primer elemento.

Comment: Nueva lista? siempre le mando el mismo array

Comment: Cuando llamas el método mandas una lista, pero cuando haces sum(rest), le mandas una lista, que no contiene el primer elemento, por tanto es una lista diferente a la cual le entró

Comment: sabes que es recursividad y como funciona??

Comment: Sí, pero recién aprendiendo, cambiaré mi pregunta por mi duda, para que me entiendas

Comment: Ya entendí , muchas gracias Randall!

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Perfecto, me alegra que hayas logrado entender.